# Expression<Func> issue

Tags: c#, .net

I'm hoping to explain this clearly and concisely. I've got an expression:

```
Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>> expression
```

that I'm trying to get the property name from. All is fine and dandy 'UNTIL', a convert expression is encountered (in the **GetPropertyName** method - this is where i want to sort the issue) i.e. normal properties may come out as `{e =>e.EmployeeID}` but in a few cases, I'm getting a result of `{e => Convert(e.EmployeeID)}`. This in effect means that I can't discern the correct property name (i don't want to parse for exceptions such as Convert() etc).

How can I cleanly extract the expression name as a property. Below is the code I'm using, so feel free to tamper with that:

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static string GetPropertyName<TObject, TProperty>(
        this Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>> expression) where TObject : class
    {
        if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call)
        {
            MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression = (MethodCallExpression)expression.Body;
            string name = ExpressionExtensions.GetPropertyName(methodCallExpression);
            return name.Substring(expression.Parameters[0].Name.Length + 1);
        }
        return expression.Body.ToString().Substring(expression.Parameters[0].Name.Length + 1);
    }

    private static string GetPropertyName(MethodCallExpression expression)
    {
        MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression = expression.Object as MethodCallExpression;
        if (methodCallExpression != null)
        {
            return GetPropertyName(methodCallExpression);
        }
        return expression.Object.ToString();
    }
}
```

and I'm invoking it as so:

```
string propertyName = expression.GetPropertyName();
// which ideally should return a value of EmployeeID or ReportsTo
// as per the usage example below
```

and this bubbles up to some arbitary usage such as:

```
var tree = items2.AsHierarchy(e => e.EmployeeID, e => e.ReportsTo);
```

Hope this gives enough info to get me off the noose!!

cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a "convert" node in your expression tree, so you should test the node for nodetype "convert", then if true go one level deeper before casting to string. Try something like this:

```
        public static string GetMemberName<TSource,TMember>(this Expression<Func<TSource,TMember>> memberReference)
    {
        MemberExpression expression = memberReference.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (expression == null)
        {
            UnaryExpression convertexp = memberReference.Body as UnaryExpression;
            if(convertexp!=null)
            expression = convertexp.Operand as MemberExpression; ;
        }
        if(expression==null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("memberReference");

        return expression.Member.Name;
    }
```

Comment: bruno -spot on. works perfectly for all scenarios that i've thrown at it. thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Have you got an example of an `{e => Convert(e.EmployeeID)}` operation?

I would guess the `Convert` is a boxing operation, i.e. it's taking a value type (presumably an `int`?) and converting to `object`. If so, and converting from `int` to `object` is the right thing to do, the `Convert` is unavoidable; you should work around it in your `GetPropertyName` method.

Comment: tim -yes, i think the GetPropertyName method is definately the correct place to do this. however, it feels 'dirty' to look for the convert in that string and parse it out. something more 'elegant' exists i feel??

Comment: By boxing, I mean having `TProperty` = `object` and `EmployeeID` declared as `int`. If this is the case, then I don't see how to avoid the `Convert` other than having `TProperty` = `int`.

Comment: tim -yes again, the boxing is unavoidable but i can live with that as the code that i use beyond that becomes iqueryable sql. my request in a nutshell is really, how can i elegantly parse out the EmployeeID section under any situation Convert() or any other boxing function, generically in the method. it may be a regex, i'm just not sure. oh, and +1 for making sense of my request!!

Comment: To do it under literally any situation, use the [visitor pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546136.aspx) over the expression and look for a property accessor. However, you'd have to wonder what stuff you'd be skipping over this technique: if you don't know what extra expression nodes you're looking for, how can you be sure they're not important?

Comment: I know for certain that I'll only be ever looking at a single property per expression.

Comment: By way of an analogy: LINQ to SQL needs to look at `Expression<>` trees and turn their contents into SQL. It doesn't ignore code that it doesn't understand; instead, it throws an exception and explains that it doesn't support the code you've given it.

Comment: tim - ok. this is actually for subsonic but i guees the same applies. what i was attempting to do was to replace some magic string field names with their property names as defined in expressions. i'm sourcing http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET23 for this stuff

Comment: tim -thanks again for your help on this. i accepted bruno's revison as it worked exactly as i'd hoped for. have a good weekend.